# vba vlookup macro not running

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a macro that preforms a vlookup across two open workbooks. I create a column named "risk" in the BJ column of the "exposure" sheet and return my vlookup values from the AK (37) column in my other wookbook (datasource.xlsx) starting in BJ2 and down until there are no more entries in the current worksheet. When I click run with my code below only "risk" appears at the top of the BJ column. I don't get an error but I'm not sure what I am doing wrong in the "with" block.

```
Sub VlookupMultipleWorkbooks()

Dim lookFor As Range
Dim srchRange As Range

Dim book1 As Workbook
Dim book2 As Workbook

Dim book2Name As String
book2Name = "datasource.xlsx"

Set book1 = ThisWorkbook
Set book2 = Workbooks(book2Name)

book1.Sheets("exposure").Range("BJ1").Formula = "risk"

With Worksheets("exposure")
        Dim lastRow As Long
        Dim i As Long

        lastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            For i = 2 To lastRow
                    Set lookFor = book1.Sheets("exposure").Cells(i, "AD")   
                    Set srchRange = book2.Sheets(1).Range("$A:$AK")   

                    Range("BJ" & i).Formula = Application.VLookup(lookFor, srchRange, 37, False)
            Next i

    End With 

End Sub
```

Comment: What error are you facing? And where does the code exit on error?

Comment: I believe you need a period in front of the Range statements.

Comment: @HavardKleven, no errors pop up when I run the code

Comment: As @igittr states, you might be missing a period. It would include the fomula in your with-statement. Maybe also try to define 'lastrow' outside the with-statement to make sure it saves before used

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to also refer to the appropriate sheets before the Range functions.